# OpenCV FPS rate decrease in one of my cameras

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, webcam, logitech

I have three Logitech Brio cameras, and I'm using OpenCV to simultaneously record videos from different angles. To achieve this, I open three threads and create a capture and VideoWriter object in each thread to capture the video frames and write them to files. I set the FPS (frames per second) rate of each camera to 60. However, when I review the recordings, I notice a discrepancy in the frame rates between the videos. Specifically, two cameras consistently maintain their frame rates, while the third camera gradually decreases its frame rate over time.

e.g.

camera1_frames_time: 00:16, 00:32, 00:48, 00:64

camera2_frames_time: 00:16, 00:32, 00:48, 00:64

camera3_frames_time: 00:16, 00:32, 00:50, 00:68

Despite my efforts to resolve the issue, I have tried several potential fixes without success:

- I attempted to address the problem by changing the camera cables.
- I also experimented with different USB ports to see if that would make a difference.
- In an attempt to isolate the issue to a specific camera, I purchased a new camera and tested it alongside the problematic one, but the frame rate still decreased.
- Tried to capture with two cameras (the 'problematic' and the good one, still FPS rate decrease)
- I even conducted tests by capturing video solely with the problematic camera, but the frame rate continued to decrease.
- In a final attempt, I replaced the problematic camera with a brand-new one, but the issue persisted.
- Additionally, I reset the camera configuration to its default settings using OBS (Open Broadcaster Software) to see if that would resolve the problem.

I have a running clock that shows milliseconds which helps me to debug the frame rate.
The script is running with Python 3, OpenCV 4.7.0.72 on Ubuntu 20.

```
 def run(self) -> None:
    """Thread runnable function."""

    self.capture = cv2.VideoCapture(int(self.src_id))
    self.capture.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FOURCC, cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('M', 'J', 'P', 'G'))
    self.capture.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 1080);
    self.capture.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 720);
    self.capture.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS, 60)
    self.capture.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_BUFFERSIZE, 10)

    width = int(self.capture.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))
    height = int(self.capture.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))
    fps = self.capture.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)

    file_name = f"recording-{self.src_id}.avi"
    out = cv2.VideoWriter(
        file_name,
        cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc("M", "J", "P", "G"),
        fps,
        (width, height)
    )

    if self.capture.isOpened():
        prev_frame_ts = 0
        while not self.done:
            (self.status, self.frame) = self.capture.read()
            if self.status:
                out.write(self.frame)
            else:
                print("could not read frame, Return")
                break
    else:
        print("Failed to open camera. source id:" + str(self.src_id))
        self.capture.release()
```

After investing considerable time in troubleshooting, I find myself running out of ideas to resolve the persistent issue. The perplexing aspect is that while two of the cameras capture frames accurately, the third camera experiences a gradual loss in frame rate over time. I'm seeking insights into the potential reasons behind this discrepancy.

Comment: "I even conducted tests by capturing video solely with the problematic camera, but the frame rate continued to decrease." can you try to run the camera with VLC or any other sofware? Maybe it's a config problem or hardware problem? If you are not able to reach the desired fps with that camera isolated at all...

Comment: Is the lighting condition for all 3 cameras the same? if not, can you try to record a static scene on all 3 cameras, and make sure to keep the lighting and the scene the same for all 3 of them? (This is to check the exposure time for all the cameras under same condition, maybe that is messing with your fps on one of the cameras)

Comment: Hello @HKay,

While I must clarify that I didn't conduct my experiments in a controlled laboratory setting, I made an effort to switch between various camera angles to observe any potential impact. Despite this attempt, I didn't notice any discernible changes. If light exposure does indeed have an effect, it would logically follow that I should have observed some sort of difference after switching angles, right? but that was not the case.

Comment: Is it always the same camera that is causing the issue? (even after shuffling all of them between usb ports)

Comment: Yes. It's always the same camera.

As previously indicated, I obtained an extra camera; however, only the same two cameras maintain a consistent and accurate frame rate, while the third camera, whether it is the new one or the old one, experiences a decrease in its frame rate.

Consequently, I embarked on a quest to explore camera configurations, and as part of my troubleshooting efforts, I attempted to reset all camera settings using OBS (Open Broadcaster Software). Regrettably, this endeavor did not yield the desired results.

Comment: Something like an automatic exposure control (which increases the exposure time to a value that can't give the high fps anymore) mentioned by @HKay is a good tip imho.

Comment: @Oded Considering two cameras are managing to maintain a consistent and accurate frame rate (60). Have you tried lowering the FPS while recording the 3 cameras? Can you try it with 30 FPS? Maybe the system is not capable of encoding/decoding the frames in time for 3 cameras.

Comment: During my recording sessions at 30 FPS, I encountered an identical issue. As stated before, attempting to record exclusively with the 'problematic' camera at 60 FPS proved unsuccessful, while I successfully managed to record with the other two cameras at 60 FPS. So, I don't think there's any encoding/decoding problem.

Comment: Can you verify the exposure experiment as that would narrow down the problem for us? what you can do is take the two cameras which record at 60 fps consistently (forget about the 3rd one for now). Run two tests, one where both cameras are under the same lighting condition, and another one which is important for us, you should cover one of the cameras so its view gets completely dark while the other camera hs a normal view with good lighting. My theory is due to the auto exposure setting their FPS would vary but please update us about your finding so we can proceed.

Comment: Thank you to both of you!
I will conduct tests on the auto-exposure feature and provide you with an update on the results.

Comment: I Downloaded the Guvcview app to monitor webcam FPS. One camera consistently showed around 53 FPS, while the rest remained steady at 60 FPS. The issue persisted despite attempting various adjustments, such as resetting settings and tinkering with exposure. Interestingly, changing the FPS setting of the problematic camera to 90 in Guvcview resulted in a display of approximately 60 FPS. However, this solution did not work when applied in OpenCV.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that there is a variation between the cameras. By adjusting multiple configuration settings, I was able to resolve the lower FPS issue with the "problematic" camera. Specifically, modifying the **exposure** and **gain** rate configuration values allowed me to achieve a frame rate close to 60 FPS.